How to bold specific words in text string - MS Word VBA
I'm very familiar with VBA in MS Excel. However, I'm totally new to VBA in MS Word.
I'm trying to do something ostensibly very straightforward: make certain text within a string bold.
I have Googled it, but most of the results relate to bolding a selection of text: i.e, the user would have to manually select it first. That's not what I want.
I have a string, named FinalText, which I want to insert into an e-mail template generated from Word. I have already worked out how to do this: add a reference to the Outlook object library, and proceed from there, with To, Subject and Body fields. That's not a problem. I just want to make certain words within the e-mail body bold.
Can anyone please give me some quick pointers? Thanks!

Maybe the last example in the documentation works for you.

VBA strings do not contain formatting information so what you wish to do is just not possible.  If you wished to indulge in jiggery pokery then format the string as you need it in word, copy to the clipboard as an rtf then somehow get the rtf into your string, but its probably not worth the hassle.

@Shrotter - I saw that, but I'm unsure how "Range" works in Word. To me, Range is an Excel thing. Fancy elaborating in an answer?

@freeflow - Yes, I understand that strings don't contain formatting information. I'm trying to build it into the e-mail, which could be rich text or HTML.

I have solved my own problem. I discovered that I could use the .HTMLBody property of the e-mail object, instead of just .Body.
Then I used the string Replace function to find the relevant text and insert <b> and </b> around it. Thanks everyone.
